# Calling a detail view inside another view if condition is true

Tags: python, django, templates, view, pycharm

I want to call a detail view inside a view if the condition is true, but I always have the same error "context must be a dict rather than str."

My code is:

```
class VotacionView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView, request):

model = Votacion
form_class = realizarVotacionForm
template_name = "RealizarVotacion.html"

success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('home')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    if not self.object.voto_rectificable:
        if UsuarioVotacion.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, Votacion=self.object).exists():
            return reverse('estadisticasvotacionsimple', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

more stuff...
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot jump out of the get_context_data method. But you can do:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    if self.jump:
        return reverse('estadisticasvotacionsimple', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
    return reverse('home')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    if not self.object.voto_rectificable:
        if UsuarioVotacion.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, Votacion=self.object).exists():
            self.jump=True
            return super(Classname, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        else:
            self.jump=False
        ......
```